# Unable to run the selenium test in parallel from the virtually created testng.xml using selenium grid

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

I used Selenium web driver + TestNG to run my selenium tests in parallel. I used three classes

**Class One (Main Class) :**

From this class i am going to start the test. Starting point of my execution.

```
 public class MainClass {

public WebDriver driver = null;

public void gid() {

    try {
        CreateTestngXml.gridHubLaunching();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    CreateTestngXml.grid("firefox", "chrome");
    driver.close();
}

public static void main(String a[]) {
    MainClass ts = new MainClass();
    try{
    ts.gid();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**Class Two (CreateTestngXml):**

public class CreateTestngXml {

```
/**
 * 
 * @param Brow
 * @param Brows
 * @code = To create a TestNg XML suite file and run it.
 */
public static void grid(String Brow, String Brows) {

    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
    suite.setName("Compatability");
    suite.setVerbose(1);
    suite.setPreserveOrder("true");
    suite.setThreadCount(4);
    suite.setParallel("tests");
    suite.setTimeOut("5000");

    // Test
    XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
    test.setName("Browser One");
    test.addParameter("Browser", Brow);

    XmlTest testOne = new XmlTest(suite);
    testOne.setName("Browser Two");
    testOne.addParameter("Browser", Brows);

    List<XmlTest> tests = new ArrayList<XmlTest>();
    tests.add(test);
    tests.add(testOne);

    // Class
    List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
    classes.add(new XmlClass("Grid.CheckGridOne"));
    test.setXmlClasses(classes);
    testOne.setXmlClasses(classes);

    suite.setTests(tests);

    // Suite
    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
    suites.add(suite);
    TestNG tng = new TestNG();
    tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
    try {
        // Running the Suite file.
        tng.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws InterruptedException
 * @code = To launch the Grid Hub and Nodes
 */
public static void gridHubLaunching() throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {

    // Launching nodes for each browser.
    String[] hub = new String[] { "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c",
            "Start", "Grid-BatchFiles\\hub.bat" };
    String[] firefox = new String[] { "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
            "/c", "Start", "Grid-BatchFiles\\firefox.bat" };
    String[] chrome = new String[] { "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
            "/c", "Start", "Grid-BatchFiles\\chrome.bat" };
    String[] ie = new String[] { "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c",
            "Start", "Grid-BatchFiles\\IE.bat" };
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(hub);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(firefox);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(chrome);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ie);
}

  }
```

`gridHubLaunching()` method is used to start the hub and the corresponding browser nodes. It has no problem in creating nodes. I ensured the creation by using `http://localhost:4444/grid/console`

**Class Third (Grid.CheckGridOne) :**

```
    public class CheckGridOne {

MainClass ts = new MainClass();
WebDriver driver = ts.driver;

DesiredCapabilities capability = null;

/**
 * 
 * @param Browser
 * @throws Exception
 * @code = To launch a Browser for Compatibility Testing purpose.
 */

@Test
@Parameters({ "Browser" })
public void browserLaunch(String Browser) throws Exception {

    // Checking condition for a Firefox.
    if (Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
        System.out.println("Firefox");

        capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
        capability.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);

        URL url = new URL(`http://lo***st:4444/wd/hub`);
        System.out.println("testing");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capability);

        System.out.println("test");
    }

    // Checking condition for a iexplorer.
    if (Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("iexplorer")) {
        System.out.println("IE");

        System.setProperty(
                "webdriver.ie.driver",
                "E:\\FW\\Test-2.28.0(Feb-18)\\IEDriverServer\\64-Bit\\IEDriverServer.exe");

        capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        capability.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
        capability.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.ANY);
        System.out.println("testing");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(
                    `http://lo***st:4444/wd/hub`), capability);
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    // Checking condition for a chrome.
    if (Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.out.println("chrome");

    }   
}
   }
```

By using the above three class i tried to run the selenium tests in parallel. My problem is it is working fine before it reaches the `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capability);` in the class third. Once it reaches the line it terminates the `TestNG suite file`. I don't know whats the problem is on my code?

**Output:**

```
  [TestNG] Running:
  Command line suite

 Firefox
 IE
 testing
 testing

 ===============================================
 Compatability
 Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
 ===============================================

 test
 test
```

The output shows the total test run as `0`. I don't know why it is showing like that.

Selenium Server - 2.28.0
TestNG - 6.1.1 & 6.8
IEDriverServer - 2.28.0

I know the question is bit big. I thought this is the correct way to explain clearly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure this part is working? `classes.add(new XmlClass("Grid.CheckGridOne"));`   i.e adding test classes to testng xml, can u post your output testng xml

Comment: Yeah. The above one is working fine. It able to call the `@Test` method inside the class. The XML file is created at run time. So, it's not possible to see the XML file externally. If you need i can post how it can create XML file.

Comment: i guess you can see created xml file under /test-output folder

Comment: @Stale: I didn't see any XML suite files there.

Comment: can you see test-output\old\Compatability folder ?

Answer (score 0):

€DIT: Why are you calling from 3rd class again back to first class? This seems like a loop.

Just define your WebDriver in your 3rd class.

```
public class CheckGridOne {

@Test
@Parameters({ "Browser" })
public void browserLaunch(String Browser) throws Exception {

WebDriver driver = null;

    // Checking condition for a Firefox.
    if (Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
        System.out.println("Firefox");

        capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
        capability.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);

        URL url = new URL(`http://lo***st:4444/wd/hub`);
        System.out.println("testing");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capability);

        System.out.println("test");
    }

    // Checking condition for a iexplorer.
    if (Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("iexplorer")) {
        System.out.println("IE");

        System.setProperty(
                "webdriver.ie.driver",
                "E:\\EproNewFW\\SWIFTest-2.28.0(Feb-18)\\IEDriverServer\\64-Bit\\IEDriverServer.exe");

        capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        capability.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
        capability.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.ANY);
        System.out.println("testing");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(
                    `http://lo***st:4444/wd/hub`), capability);
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    // Checking condition for a chrome.
    if (Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.out.println("chrome");

    }   
}
   }
```